# which payment gateway I have to use for Bar's drink purchasing iOS app?

Tags: ios, paypal

I am developing Drink purchasing app for bar. I want to use Paypal payment gateway for my APP.I am confused should apple accept Paypal for my Drink App.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read section 3.1.1 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase).

The very basic idea is you have to use IAP for any in-app content like game credits, unlimited swipes, unlocking bonus content, etc.   You should not use IAP for any out-of-app purchases, like an Uber ride or a drink at a bar.  Meaning, PayPal should be fine.

I use and like Stripe.

But it's up to you to review those guidelines and judge for your specific case.

Comment: @ Frankie Thanks it help me

Comment: @Sam I'm glad I could help.  If you found my answer useful and would like to accept/upvote my answer it would be appreciated.  Good luck.